Parallel calls in a sequence diagram with TikZ-UML
I am currently learning to use TikZ-UML to draw sequence diagrams and I am struggling to handle parallel calls.
The situation is:
C is supposed to call opa() to both B and D that process it in the exact same way (opb() to themselves and opc() to A) but B and D need to stay separated because they don't act the same as the other for the rest of the program. My best attempt so far is the image below with the corresponding code:

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{makebox}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{ % To center a diagram wider than \textwidth

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{umlseqdiag}
    
    % Define actors
    \umlobject[no ddots]{A}
    \umlobject[no ddots, fill=blue!30]{B}
    \umlobject[no ddots, fill=green!50]{C}
    \umlobject[no ddots, fill=blue!15]{D}
    
    \begin{umlcall}[dt=9, op={opa()}, padding= -2]{C}{B}
        \begin{umlcallself}[op={opb()}]{B}
        \end{umlcallself}
        \begin{umlcall}[dt=-1.5, type=return, op={opc()}]{B}{A}
        \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlcall}
    
    \begin{umlcall}[dt=-7, op={opa()}, padding= -5.5]{C}{D}
        \begin{umlcallself}[op={opb()}]{D}
            \begin{umlcall}[type=return]{D}{A}
            \end{umlcall}
        \end{umlcallself}
    \end{umlcall}

    \end{umlseqdiag}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}

To mimic a parallel execution, I used dt= but it doesn't seem reliable as the lengths of the different processes for B, C and D are not the same (using padding just breaks the values of dt)
Another problem I don't know how to tackle is the opc() call that is supposed to come from B and C towards A but the two processes overlap. I here do not repeat opc() for both arrows as it seems clear that they represent the same call, but I am doing unreliable things again.
Thanks in advance for your help !
